# Error when importing .xslx/.csv file to MySQL database

Tags: microsoft-excel, mysql, csv, phpmyadmin

I have a simple .xlsx file which I filled in manually and which looks like this: 
[image]

When I open this file in TextEdit nothing shows up and (therefore) this file cannot be imported to the MySQLServer at `PhpMyAdmin`.

I saved the same file as .csv . When I open this file in TextEdit then this what I get:

```
id, questions, keywords, answer

1,here1,here2,here3
```

and (therefore) the .csv cannot be directly imported to the MySQLServer at `PhpMyAdmin` but I get the following error:

```
Error
Static analysis:

5 errors were found during analysis.

A symbol name was expected! A reserved keyword can not be used as a column name without backquotes. (near "int" at position 46)
At least one column definition was expected. (near "int" at position 46)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "1" at position 50)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "`question`" at position 54)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "varchar" at position 65)
SQL query:

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Sample`.`TABLE 3` ( int(1), `question` varchar(5), `keywords` varchar(5), `answer` varchar(5)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'int(1), `question` varchar(5), `keywords` varchar(5), `answer` varchar(5)) DEFAU' at line 1
```

If I simply add double quotes at the .csv file at Textedit by writing it in the following way:

```
id, questions, keywords, answer

"1","here1","here2","here3"
```

then the table is properly imported to the database.

**Why I cannot simply write down some things at my excel file save it either as .xlsx or as .csv and directly have the right form at TextEdit so that this can be imported successfully at the MySQLServer?**

The window with the options when I try to import the table at the database looks like this:

[image]

I have already imported many .odt files (Libre Office) like this to the database but it seems that Libre Office was taking caring of this these things automatically whereas Excel does not.

Comment: I suspect this is to do with what data type your database is expecting. Is the "ID" attribute described as an integer? What about the other 3? It looks to me like your database expects strings hence why it throws an error when it gets other datatypes.
Note I am not an expert and only throwing an idea in the air, it may be wrong.

Comment: Thank for your comment. You are actually right. If I replace 1 with here0 then the csv file is properly imported to the database even though it does not contain any double quotes (but they are added automatically by the database). But I am pretty sure that with Libre Office .odt files were automatically containing double quotes at the TextEdit so the file could be readily imported to the database even though it was containing numbers at the spreadsheet.

Comment: Also as I can see, for this reason, the `id` column was saved as `int` type at the database when I imported the .odt file whereas the `id` column is saved as `varchar` type at the database when I imported the .csv file formed in Excel.

Comment: But now for some reason I start to understand that the error is about what I posted above `"A symbol name was expected! A reserved keyword can not be used as a column name without backquotes."` that is  because I use `id` as the name of the first column. If I change this then all things are working fine. However, I did not have any problem yet to import as many tables as I wanted which has this column name. Therefore, I have no idea what is really happening here... :(